# Which is more efficient -> hibernate criteria-mysql query?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am developing a web based app using spring and hibernate - mySql.. I have a restriction that user name must be unique. So which is more efficient way? to use a `hibernate criteria` for checking the user exists or not? Or defining `unique` in database and then use a try catch?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use both. The Hibernate query will allow checking functionally that the user doesn't exist before inserting it, and return an appropriate result or throw an appropriate exception. It's better than relying on a unique constraint that will cause the transaction to rollback with a cryptic error message deeply hidden inside an stack of exceptions.

But you should also have a unique constraint to guarantee the uniqueness, simply in case two concurrent threads both check that the user doesn't exist at the same time, then both insert the same user at the same time.

For simple queries which don't need to be dynamically composed, I would use HQL rather than Criteria though: much more readable IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use criteria and return true or false:

```
public boolean clientNameValidation(String clientName) {

        Criteria criteriaOfClient = criteria();

        criteriaOfClient.add(Restrictions.eq("clientName", clientName));

        List<Client> results = (List<Client>) criteriaOfClient.list();
        if (results.size() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```